# jQTouch list bullets not showing

Tags: css, jqtouch

I am trying jQTouch for an iPhone web app, but I want content on the pages to be able to have normal bullet lists, not styled as the bars in the jqt theme. So I am trying to override the css selectors in the theme.css:

```
#jqt .content ul {
color: #fff;
    border: none;
font: inherit;
padding: 0;
margin: 15px 10px 17px 10px;
}

#jqt .content ul li {
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;

    list-style-type:disc;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-image: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It works fine in that it overrides it, but I don't get any visible list bullets. Any ideas why?

Comment: how do you know it overrides it? could you put the code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite the `li` (not the `ul`)

**CSS:**

```
div#jqt #textpage li
{
    list-style-type:disc;
    padding: 7px 20px 0px 10px; /* set these as required */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- PAGE 2d -->       
<div id="page-2d">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Page Heading</h1>
        <a class="back" href="#page-2">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div id="textpage" >
        <h1>My heading</h1><br />
        <p>Stuff</p> 
        <p>More Stuff</p><br />
        <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
        <!-- Note No <ul> works don't know why -->  
        <li>My List Item1 </li>
        <li>My List Item2 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overflow hidden seems to be the problem, based on a quick test i did.

This is what i am using for my project and its working like a charm:

```
ul.text, .text ul
{
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
ul.text li, .text ul li
{
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    filter: 0; // hide IE gradient
    margin-left: 19px;
    background: transparent; 
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check the display type on the LI. I had this issue because they were set to "block" when they should have been "list-item"